# What exactly does Vim need from you to make a separate folder for your scripts?

Tags: vimscript

Every <s>coding</s> configuration need I have for Vim works just fine if I put it all in the `.vimrc` file, but I'm curious: let's just say that I wanted to make my own scripts or plugins, and my `.vimrc` file was becoming too cluttered.

According to google, the format for plugins is `~/. vim/pack/vendor/start/plugin_name`, and that's exactly what my tpope surround plugin uses, but I'm wondering how somebody would have a separate folder for their vim scripts, especially considering that linux wouldn't let you have two `pack` directories in the same directory for good reason.

How else (other than the .vimrc file in your home folder) do Vim programmers get Vim to read external files that allow the user to have separate VimScripts?

Comment: I"m not sure I understand your question. I believe it would help me if you could illustrate it. Could you tell us which `.vimrc` setting you would like to depend on the script you are editing? Or do you only want to split your `.vimrc` into multiple files for the sake a readability?

Comment: @Vivian: it's a pretty straightforward question, I'm only trying to figure how you could put vim settings in separate files and folders. Nothing I have tried so far has worked except the .vimrc file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simple things, I would just create a single file per "project" and place them directly into `~/.vim/plugin/<file>.vim`. Create the `plugin` folder if it does not exist. Vim will automatically source those. For even more sophisticated things, you can make use of autoloading, see (the unhelpful help tag) [:h 52.3](https://vimhelp.org/usr_52.txt.html#52.3)

That's how we did it before `pack` where a thing and when we did not have plugin manager plugins. Good old times :)

Comment: yeah it does appear that this method works, and from now on i will use a top-level "plugin" folder inside of .vim for all my custom scripts.

Answer (score 3):

In `~/.vim/pack/vendor/start/plugin_name`, the variable parts are: `~/.vim/pack/{vendor}/start/{plugin_name}`, where:

- `vendor` and `plugin_name` are totally arbitrary names,
- the package name `vendor` can be anything that a) makes sense to *you* and b) doesn't break your filesystem,
- `plugin_name` can also be anything but it kind of makes sense to use the plugin's name and not some silly crap.

Basically, Surround will work just as well if you put it here:

```
~/.vim/pack/vendor/start/surround
```

or there:

```
~/.vim/pack/LOL/start/badaboum
```

as will any competently written plugin.

Now, you can have **more than one *package* under `pack/`**. That's, like, the whole point of that scheme. It lets you keep your own stuff and third-party stuff separate, **in packages**:

```
~/.vim/pack/mine/…
~/.vim/pack/theirs/…
```

FWIW, this is what I currently have:

```
~/.vim/pack/bundle/    " for QOF plugins like surround
~/.vim/pack/lab/       " for my own experimental stuff
~/.vim/pack/lang/      " for language-specific plugins, custom and third-party alike
```

`:help startup` is a good entry point about this. See also `:help usr_51` and `:help package`.

If the *relative* complexity of packages is too much, you can still use the old way, with `~/.vim/plugin/`, `~/.vim/ftplugin/`, etc. It still works and the new way, with packages, is really just the same, with an additional segregation layer that makes things cleaner.

[This article](https://vimways.org/2018/from-vimrc-to-vim/) covers the old way *very well*.

Comment: That's a great answer to the question for beginners, but i it's still not clear to me whether "plugin" and "pack". By default, tim pope's "pack" was installed with "pack" being located inside of the .vim directory. That works, but putting my scripts inside of his directory doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Why would you put your scripts inside of "his directory"? And what do you call "his directory" to begin with?

Comment: Uhm, I'm more or less concerned with how vim reads from "pack", is vim instructed by default to read from both both "pack" and "plugin" inside of the .vim directory?

Comment: Everything is explained in the provided help sections.

Comment: that's nice, but your answer doesn't answer my question. You've shown you've put some effort into this, but my concern has more to do with how vim itself reads your changes to the configuration, and how exactly plugin writers add their directories to runtimepath rather than the naming conventions. I tried adding my scripts to his directories to see if vim would recognize them there but clearly there's something more going on here that isn't being explained in a straightforward manner.

Comment: Well, how about you answer my request for clarification so we can move forward? And yes, your questions are all answered in the linked resources. 1. Vim doesn't generally read configuration change. If you change something, then you start a new session or you source the changed script manually. 2. Plugin writers (I am one) just put their plugin's directory in whatever package they consider suitable. 3. Again adding "your script" to "his directories" is pointless. Just read the relevant help and create your own directories as demonstrated in my answer.

Comment: To me, "his directory" was the folder "pack" under his directory tree for the surround plugin. There's nothing pointless about trying to figure out how something works. I can't ask better questions if you refuse to confront the questions I have asked directly. Putting your scripts in .vim/plugin works, how do developers such as yourself get the scripts using the "pack" scheme to work?

Comment: No, the folder "pack" is not part of Surround. It's not "his", it's "yours". We get this to work by reading the documentation, understanding it, and putting it into practice, not by trying random things and making wild assumptions. The "package" feature is explained under `:help 'package'`. Read it.

Comment: Okay, then it would be better for you not to respond to questions if the help documentation is enough.

Comment: Plus, i referred to tim pope's directories as "his" because they were created per the install instructions for the plugin, they are technically "mine" because i fallowed the instructions, but i still have no idea why vim reads his files at startup like i've been trying to figure out this whole time. All I know is that somehow, those directories were added to vim's runtimepath. I've been looking at the surround install instructions this morning, there's no indications of what went on to make it work.

Comment: I already pointed out where to find all the information you are looking for. You are hopeless.

Comment: And for some reason, you still seem to be unable to find said information or answer questions in a way that makes any sense at all.

Comment: oh hey, @romainl, i was reading vim help pages earlier today and there was some real neat and useful information about how to configure things for an Amiga. Thank you so much, i'm totally now convinced that you have superior intelligence and you don't waste time with worthless information!

Answer (score 0):

I would create an additional file and source it into the `.vimrc`.

```
._ ~
  |_ .vimrc
  |
  |_ vimfiles
    |_ settings.vim
```

E.g. create a `~/vimfiles/settings.vim` and within `~/.vimrc` add

```
source ~/vimfiles/settings.vim
```

If you want to execute a `settings.vim` next to your `.vimrc` wherever it is.

```
._ myfolder
  |_ .myvimrc
  |_ settings.vim
```

You could do:

```
execute 'source' expand('<sfile>:h') . '/settings.vim'
```

Comment: That's almost exactly the same as putting files `~/.vim/plugin`, except that plugin files are loaded after a vimrc (and presumably in some kind of sorted order). Unless you need some very specific ordering, `~/.vim/plugin` is much easier.

Comment: @Vivian, thank you for answering in a straightforward way, that's a lot better than cyberbullying strangers online.

Comment: We try to establish a warmful atmosphere around Vim but some of our best experts have a particular sense of humor that may spoil the cosyness feeling we try to create :-D Be sure we are a number to protect you from the misunderstanding ;-) Welcome to Vim :-)